# Trying to install volta.sh package library

Tags: apt, bash, nodejs, curl

I am trying to install `volta.sh` package library from which I wish to install `Node.js` and `npm` in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I tried:

```
curl https://get.volta.sh | bash
```

and got the error:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: get.volta.sh
```

I edited the `.bashrc` and added the code:

```
export VOLTA_HOME="$HOME/.volta"
export PATH="$VOLTA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

I then closed and reopened the Ubuntu terminal, and tried again, getting the same error. Have also tried

```
sudo apt install nodejs
```

Which does not work.
I am trying to work out what is wrong. Even to update

```
sudo apt update
```

results in errors:

```
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
```

I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installed.

Comment: This sounds like a more general network problem - can you `dig get.volta.sh` or `ping -c4 security.ubuntu.com` or do you get similar resolver errors? Can you ping hosts by ip ex. `ping -c4 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I thought it would be related somehow to network connection because of the failure to respond kind of messages. Though not sure how to resolve.
These are the responses I get to the commands:
dig get.volta.sh
net.c:536: probing sendmsg() with IP_TOS=b8 failed: Network is unreachable
; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> get.volta.sh
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

ping -c4 security.ubuntu.com
ping: security.ubuntu.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

ping -c4 8.8.8.8
ping: connect: Network is unreachable